Residue of a complex function at an essential singularity
I'm trying to find the residue at $z=0$ of the following function:
$$ f(z) = z^{10} \ e^{ \frac{1}{z^2} } $$
So I start by expanding the exponential term into Laurent series:
$$ e^{ \frac{1}{z^2} } = 1 + \frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{2z^4} + ... + \frac{1}{n! z^{2n} } + .. $$
Multiplying by $z^{10}$:
$$f(z) = z^{10} + z^8 + \frac{z^6}{2} + ... + \frac{z^{10-2n}}{n!} + .. $$
Since we only have even exponents of $z$ and no $\frac{1}{z}$ term, does that mean that the residue at $z=0$ is zero? or am I missing something?

Yes, that is correct.
